# ue4 prerequisites repeat installation？

Tags: unreal-engine4, vcredist

The Satisfactory game can only be run after the first installation, the second time it must be uninstalled to enter the game, and the third installation...

> **I asked the official customer service, no one responded**

> https://steamcommunity.com/app/526870/discussions/1/3115897635597823194/

it didn't work for me.

The game can run without ue4 prerequisites installed,But the game will check if the ue4 prerequisites are exited correctly and can compile a program to replace the ue4 prerequisites

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't expect to just write a program and then exit normally.

golang：

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println("0")
}
```